# How to sort through asc and desc in php codes in a website

Tags: php

apparently i have run into some problems. I will show 2 images of my work along with my codes. Apparently the first image will show a table of my request data that is sorted through asc. However for the second image, it will show a table whereby the variable will display the data taken from the second row instead from the one on top. Apparently I want it to be the variable ' Lee ' instead of ' Kenny ' at the request which is a data much later on.

Codes for History of request:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT requestby, requestno, session FROM allocation ORDER BY session ASC");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($requestby, $requestno, $session);
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Request By</b></td><td><b>Request Amount</b></td><td><b>Date - Time</b></td><td><b>Remove</b></td></tr>";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td>$requestby</td><td> $requestno</td> <td>$session</td> <td><a href = 'deletereqno.php?session=$session'>Remove</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
if ($requestby && $requestno && $session)
{}
else {
    $requestby = null; 
    $requestno = null; 
    $session = null; 
    echo '<p style="color:red;">No one has requested for any taxi vouchers</p>';
}
```

Codes for Allocation

```
<tr align ="center">
<td width="10%"><input type="number" min=1000000000 max=9999999999 name="rangefrom" maxlength="10" size="10" value="" required></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="number" min=1000000000 max=9999999999 name="rangeto" maxlength="10" size="10" value="" required></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="requestby" maxlength="15" size="15" value="<?php echo $requestby ?>" readonly></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="session" maxlength="15" size="15" value="<?php echo $date ?>" readonly></td>
<td width="50%"><input type="text" name="comments" maxlength="30" size="30" value="Nill" placeholder="Leave it 'Nill' if there is no comments" required></td>
```

Preview!
[History of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDRTm.png)

[Allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6N2d.png)

Comment: from what I gather, you'd need to add a WHERE clause.

Comment: ~Look into [**JQuery dataTables**](https://www.datatables.net/) . Does exactly what you want without repetative calls to the SQL.

Comment: Without a `WHERE` clause your SQL query will always return every result. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes there is nth wrong with the data, i want it to be that way, is just i have issue sorting it, like as you can see from the first image, i want it to be sorted through asc, however, the data from the second image, is clearly showing the variable 'kenny' instead of 'lee'.

Comment: The kenny record is later, why do you expect that to be first?

Comment: so yeah thats the issue im facing, is there a way to read the earlier data?
Because if i sort it by desc at the php, it will show lee. Which is the one i one, but, the history of allocation table will also be sorted by desc

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying there. Can you rephrase that comment? Also use the `@`, notifications arent sent otherwise.

Comment: You could grab all the results into an array first ... Then use it one direction, then `array_reverse`, and use it the other direction. That will allow you to continue re-using the data without losing access to it. Since grabbing it from the database is a one-by-one as you have it.